# angularjs add item to object array

Tags: arrays, angularjs, object

I have a set of array and object that look like this

`

```
var PaymentContent = "Payments":
     [{
        "Details": {
                    "PaymentType": "CreditCard",
                    "Amount": $scope.total,
                    "CCNAME": $scope.Form.CreditCard.FullName,
                      }
      }]
Payments: Array[1]
0:Object
 Details: Object
 Amount: 5.99
 CCNAME: null
 PaymentType: "CreditCard"`
```

Now, how can i update that set of objects and array using angularjs?
desired output :

`Payments: Array[1]
0:Object
 Details: Object
 Amount: 5.99
 CCNAME: null
 PaymentType: "CreditCard"
LastPayment: "04/11/2011"`

Notice the lastpayment field.

Here is my code

`var paymentDetails = {LastPayment : '04/11/2011', LastSignOn : '04/11/2011'}
fields = angular.extend({}, PaymentContent , paymentDetails);`

Thanks!

Comment: You should show your complete object interaction code. BTW adding a property to existing object is just like assigning one like a.LastPayment = "sample";

Comment: you could easily add LastPayment in payment array by `Payments[0].LastPayment = '04/11/2011'`

Comment: @Alex the thing you are talking is not reproduceable..could you please try reproduce it here http://jsfiddle.net/78y9T/73/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting an empty object as destination. This new object will receive the properties and values of the other 2 objects...without changing those other 2 source objects

If you want the array object to receive the updates remove the first argument ( the empty object)

```
angular.extend( fields.Payments[0].Details, paymentDetails);
```

This will update `fields.Payments[0].Details` with all of the properties and values in `paymentDetails`

[**Demo Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/78y9T/74/)

Answer (score 2):

You can directly write below code:

```
Payments[0].LastPayment = "04/11/2011";
```